# Why is my state not changing and why doesnt my reference to {store.getState()} not appear at all?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am new to React and Redux and I am having trouble.  The code below doesn't update my state to 7 as I expect it to, and the  area doesn't render anything, not even the default.

I have been trying for a couple of days to research this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

````
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Button, View } from 'react-native'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'


// Define the initial state of our store
const initialState = { count: 5 }

// Define a reducer
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'NUMBER':
      return { ...state, count: 7 }, console.log("test2", state.count, action.payload);
    default:
      return state, console.log("test");
  }
};


// Create a store, passing our reducer function and our initial state
const store = createStore(reducer)

/// We're done! Redux is all set up. Here's how we can use it:

// Calling `store.getState()` returns our state object
export default function App() {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View>
        <Text style={{ height: 100, fontSize: 30 }}>
          {store.getState()}
        </Text>
        <Button
          title='Button'
          onPress={() => { store.dispatch({ type: 'NUMBER', payload: 6 }) }}
        />
      </View>
    </Provider >
  )
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing your console.log statements. I think they're preventing the state from getting updated:

```
return { ...state, count: 7 }, console.log("test2", state.count, action.payload);
```

and here

```
return state, console.log("test");
```

if you want to log, then do it before the return:

```
console.log({ state, action })
return state
```

Try `JSON.stringify(store.getState())` to render a JSON representation of your state.

Answer (score 2):

Actually redux have changed the count but Text view does not listen to change . To observe change in redux you have to connect the component and make separate component

try this

```
import { Provider, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

......

export const Count = () => {
  const count = useSelector(state => {return state && state.count?state.count:0}  );
  return (
    <Text style={{ height: 100, fontSize: 30 }}>
          {count}
   </Text>
  );
};
.....

<View>
        <Count />

.....
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made the change but now I get an error that says "An error occurred while selecting the store state: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.count')."

Comment: @MatthewWeinkle updated answer . try this const count = useSelector(state => {return state && state.count?state.count:0}

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the code:

store.dispatch({ type: 'NUMBER', payload: 6 })

Into:

store.dispatch(() => { return {type: 'NUMBER', payload: 6} })

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I changed it to what you suggested but unfortunately it doesn't work.  I get "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."    Thanks again.